# Eclipse error: org.eclipse.core.nternal.resources.Project cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder

Tags: java, eclipse

I have jdk 1.8.0_191 and Eclipse 2019-12.

This is what I'm doing:

- Opening Eclipse
- File > New > Dynamic Web Project
- Fill Project name > Click next
- On "Source folders on build path" it's empty. I just click next.
- Fill "context root" and "content directory" with a value
- Check "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor"
- Click finish

Getting the following error when I click "Finish":

```
Failed while installing Java 1.8
```

Then there's an "Ok" and a "Details" button.

When I click "Details" it says:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder
```

Then I click "ok", it closes the window and creates a folder with the project name. But the folder is empty. It does not contain all of the other files and folders that should be there for a Dynamic Web Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.

Executed the same process in Eclipse 2021-03 and it worked.

Realized that the issue was on the second screen ("Source folders on build path").

In Eclipse 2021-03 that screen came already filled with the following info:

- Source folders on build path: src\main\java
- Default output folder: build\classes

But on Eclipse 2019-12 those two fields were empty.
So I just added that same info manually, proceeded to the end and it worked fine.

For some reason those fields are empty in that version of Eclipse in my machine (not sure if that's default for that version or it's something in mine. Most likely the second.).

Anyway, filling them manually resolves the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: see also this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578048

Comment: Ah, I duplicated this by trying to upgrade a regular Eclipse to the Java EE version. It works if I download the entire Java EE Eclipse manually.

Comment: How to do this , please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You might find more details in file `$workspace/.metadata/.log` - most of the times something that goes wrong internally shows up there before the problem gets visible to you (the cast exception is probably a follow-up error, and in itself not telling much).

If there's nothing immediately remedying in there, you could file a bug report in the Eclipse bug tracker (with log file provided), and hope that someone will investigate what might have gone wrong in the two year old release.

Does the problem persists with current versions of Eclipse and JDK (where development is focused)?

Comment: I opened the log file you recommended. It shows the same error with some additional detailing lines such as "at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.internal.JavaFacetInstallDelegate.createFolder(JavaFacetInstallDelegate.java:192)". Can't post everything here in the comments because there's not enough space. Anyway, I found the issue. Just posted an answer detailing it. Thanks for your help.